# Copy files from an autoexec jar to java.io.tmpdir

Tags: java, file, copy, dir, temp

I'm trying to copy two local files from my jar to the java temp dir defines like that :

`String strDirectoy = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + path;`

It works great when I launch it from eclipse, but when I try to launch it from the exported autoexec jar, it does'nt work !

Did I missed something ?

Comment: Can you post the actual copy code? What error or misbehavior are you getting? Please supply more detail.

Comment: Maybe you should see [this thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/122909/loading-images-from-executable-jar-file#), specifically [this post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/122909/loading-images-from-executable-jar-file#post601961)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know what I've done wrong : 
- First : eclipse does'nt export my own files (the ones I wanted to copy)
So I have to copy them in the jar manually after it had been exported by eclipse.

- Second : I have to put them in the main directory of the jar, if I don't do that, java can't find the files in question.